# Unable to run VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I try to run my VS2015, it ends up with the below error.

I tried all possible ways to extend its validity, but in vein. Even I tried reinstalling VS2015 twice following few suggestions from team. But, nothing has helped me to unlock.

Even changing date to olden days, removing account & re-adding account, uninstall & restart & reinstall etc, dint help me at all.

Please suggest how I can unlock this to run VS2016.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need a license key, reinstalling the product will not help, get a license key and click the "Unlock wit ha product Key", enter the key and it should work if the key is valid

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Edition require to buy the license. It provide a limited evaluation time. 
You have to buy the license key https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/ 
Or just uninstall and switch to Community Edtion.